# Insert in EntityListener cause ConcurrentModificationException in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have an entity listener for finding changes on selected entities.

```
@PostUpdate
@PostPersist
void onChange(RhEntity data) {
    InjectHelper.getInstance().inject(this, this.changeService);
    if (ReflectionUtils.hasChangeListener(data.getClass()))
        changeService.persistAndNotifyAll(data, DataChange.DATA_CHANGE_TYPE_INSERT_OR_UPDATE);
}
```

When transaction finishes, on commit Hibernate throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.services.PersonDataUtils.getNaturalPerson(PersonDataUtils.java:65)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.services.PersonDataUtils.initPersonData(PersonDataUtils.java:92)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.services.PersonDataUtils$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6b46a725.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.services.PersonDataUtils$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13329715.initPersonData(<generated>)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.units.DataChangeListenerTest.beforeMethod(DataChangeListenerTest.java:53)
    at com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.RhAuthenticatedTest.setup(RhAuthenticatedTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 51 more
```

I config hibernate with Spring,

** this code works when I am using `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Answer (score 5):

The JPA 2.1 specification says (3.5.2) :

> The following rules apply to lifecycle callback methods:
>
> ...
>
> - Lifecycle
>     callbacks can invoke JNDI, JDBC, JMS, and enterprise beans. Entity
>     Listeners and Callback Methods Java Persistence 2.1,
> - In
>     general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>     invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity
>     instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>     context[46]. [47] A lifecycle callback method may modify the
>     non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

You can't really change the persistent state of an managed object in this callback.

Moreover, Hibernate has an issue about this : [HHH-7537](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7537). This issue is closed because the lifecycle callback - as yours - didn't follow the specification. You can do this kind of thing by openning a new transaction (ie with Spring, using `REQUIRE_NEW` on the lifecycle methods)

Comment: Is there any solutions for doing it in same transaction? I use Hibernate Interceptor, but it insert in new transaction

Comment: I haven't. to be honest, I always try to avoid those lifecycle callback : it's too easy to introduce issue with performances or locks. I try to maintain related states in my business layer

Answer (score 3):

Iv'e solved my problem in a Spring Framework app by doing this:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) //it means a new transaction will be created 
public class MyService {
 ...
}

@Component
public class MyListener {

    private static MyService myService;

@Autowired
    public void setMyService (MyService myService) {
        MyListener.myService= myService;
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void myPostUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
//      entity.setModificationDate(new Date());
        myService.methodBar(entity.getBar());//calling some method
    }

    @PostPersist
    public void myPostPersist(MyEntity entity) {
        myService.methodFoo(entity.getFoo());//calling some method
    }  

}


@Entity
@Table(name= "TB_MY_ENTITY")
@DynamicUpdate
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
    ....
}
```

I hope this could help !